# GIMP induvidually rotating multiple layers at once

Tags: gimp, layers, rotate

I have several layers that I all want to rotate by a certain degree. Not as a group all together around a common central point, but rather all around their individual center. Grouping or chaining the layers only does the former. Am I missing a simple trick here, or is there no other possibility than going into each and every layer and adjust the rotation one by one?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that is better achieved using vector software where you can apply transforms to objects individually. GIMP/Photoshop and other raster software has nothing like this. It can be done in Inkscape pretty easily - [See example](https://imgur.com/a/yWtNe01).

Comment: Good point! Thanks.